# Not Able to filter the Table Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am learning power BI , for one of my requirement i want to filter table based on the selected value from the slicer and show it in different slicer.

[image]

So, here there are 4 slicer and based on selection of one slicer i have to populate the data for the 2nd.

My Table Looks Like

```
id Name     ParentId
1  A        null
2  A.1      1
3  A.1.B.1  2
```

So, i have only 1 table where i have to search the element by id -> parentId and then populate it in the next slicer.

e.g: if We select A then in the next slicer we should show A.1 since , id --> 1(A) = ParentId --> 1(A.1)

I tried to create separate table and then link the id with parentid in the mapping section , this concept is working but not the problem is .

If we select A then in 2nd combo A.1 and A.2 is displaying , but as we click on A.1 on the 2nd combo and then try to click on the elements on 1st combo here in our case A , then the filter is not working properly .

If appending the elements from previous selection + New selection

e.g:

```
Slicer 1    Slicer 2
A  --       (1,2,3)
B  --       (4,5,6)
```

> Now , after clicking on A[1st Slicer] it shows (1,2,3) [2nd Slicer]
>
> After clicking on 2 [2nd Slicer] --> showing some elements in  [3rd
> slicer]
>
> But, now again click on B [1st slicer] --> [4,5,6,2] (Wrong value)
> since we selected 2 its appending with the new selection only if we
> click on the 2nd slicer.

So, as an alternate solution I tried to filter the selected value which is measure from the table and then show it in the list.

> My expression:

```
Table = FILTER(TableA, TableA[id] == Tableb[selectedId] )
```

> Tableb[selectedId] --> is measure

```
Table = FILTER(TableA, TableA[id] == "8DE04141-E5B6-49E1-814A-ADB4C6FF5DCF" ) --> selected Id
```

1st statement is not showing any value but the 2nd giving me the result when i am hard coding value , please suggest me what i can do here.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to filter table based on the selected value from the slicer and show it in different slicer.

You don't need DAX for that.  You just set up the correct relationships and set filters and slicers in the report.

Comment: Browne I have 4 slicer and output of 1 is input to another . I can achieve it by setting relation between column but when i am clicking on 1st slicer it's showing correct data. But when i am clicking on 2nd slicer and then 1st its slowing data from 1st and 2nd in 2nd slicer and when i am clicking on 2nd slicer then its getting corrected.

Comment: Browne Microsoft added screenshot.

Comment: Update your question to add the tables and relationships and clearly indicate your desired behavior.  I still don't understand what you are trying to acomplish.

Comment: Browne updated the question.